# Bluetooth startDiscovery() is not working on Android 10

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I´ve got stuck on a problem. I´ve tried some hints from Stack Overflow and other websites.

I would like to program an app, which searches for all Bluetooth devices around and if the matching device has been found (MAC-Address as reference), the app will start a connection.

Therefore I have programmed a test application to test the discovery-function. BUT there is unfortunately a big problem with starting the discovering process on my Android 10 device. I´ve got an older Samsung S3 Mini with Android 4.1.2 (SDK 16) on it, where my code is working fine. 
On the Android 10 device `startDiscovery()` returns false, different to the Android 4 device, which returns true. On the android developer page they say, that false is the returning value, if an error has occurred. The BroadcastReceiver should work fine, because the app on the Android 9 mobile phone detects that a Bluetooth search has been started in the settings. It is only the `startDiscovery()` function, which the problem is all about (in my opinion).

I am checking all permissions and the Bluetooth state before starting the discovering-process. But i think, it can´t be the written code, because it works perfectly on the older device.  Maybe I have something missing for newer devices.

### Edit

As Thomas Morris explains below, in Android 10 you need the location turned on by the user. In Android 9 or lower, Thomas Morris answer is correct, because in all SDKs below 29, only the permission is needed and not the enabled location service.

Is there a solution to avoid asking the user to turn on the location themselves?

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String TAG = "MainActivity";
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
int status = 0;     //0 = start discovering, 1 = cancel discovering

public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    checkBluetoothState();

    final Button test = findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(status == 0) {
                if(bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    if (checkCoarseLocationPermission()) {
                        Boolean result = bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); //start discovering and show result of function
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start discovery result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Start discovery: " + result);
                        test.setText("Stop");
                        status = 1;
                    }
                }else{
                    checkBluetoothState();
                }
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Stop");
                status = 0;
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                test.setText("Start");
            }
        }
    });

    checkCoarseLocationPermission();
}

private boolean checkCoarseLocationPermission() {
    //checks all needed permissions
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}

private void checkBluetoothState() {
    //checks if bluetooth is available and if it´s enabled or not
    if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device is discovering...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to enabled bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent enabledIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enabledIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }
    }
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            Log.d(TAG,"Device found: " + deviceName + "|" + deviceHardwareAddress);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FOUND: " + deviceName + "|" + deviceHardwareAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            //report user
            Log.d(TAG,"Started");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //change button back to "Start"
            status = 0;
            final Button test = findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
            test.setText("Start");
            //report user
            Log.d(TAG,"Finished");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FINISHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
            final int extra = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,-1);
            if(extra == (BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)) {
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                Boolean b = bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start discovery" + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH){
        checkBluetoothState();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);

    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}



}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Have you allowed permissions when you run the application. You need to go into the app settings and enable location. Then turn location and bluetooth on. Also you need to check if your phone as the required API level.

Comment: Thank you, the solution is, as so often, too easy. The location was never turned on, so that only Bluetooth was always enabled. Now all I have to do is get the app to turn location on.
I asked for the location permission, which was also allowed in the app settings, but I had to switch on the location manually. If I do that, the discovering-process works fine.

Comment: I have posted a more detailed answer for you please could you approve it for other users benefit. Also added some code which should give you a popup for it. If you have to reinstall the app its annoying to do manually. Why not use a popup.

Comment: You are scanning so I don't think this is the issue but for any poor fellow like myself trawling the internet for Android 10 issues I discovered that if you don't scan before connecting on Android 10 you will get a Gatt 133. I resolved the issue by checking if paired and if not doing a scan. Disable/Enable BT before you test to confirm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enable location permission on the application. To do this go to:

- Android phone settings
- App & notifications
- See all app
- Locate your application and select it
- Permissions
- Allow location slide it on

Then

- Turn bluetooth on the device on
- Turn location on the device on

Or some code to do it automatically via a popup (call in oncreate method)

```
public void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,}, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        } else {
            checkPermission();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still have a question, why does it work in Android 9 or lower if I only ask that I can use the location (but not turn it on), but in Android 10 I have to turn the location on? A buddy’s phone has Android 9, on his phone works it without turning on the location. He only has to give permission to use the location.

Comment: Not 100% sure but location is a issue for security reasons. Therefore later versions need to get the permission from the user. The app can not simply give it. Kinda like giving a company permission to store your data so you can use there service. As using ble it is possible to get location information from someone. These laws re relatively recent therefore on android 10 not 9. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would ruin the sense of the app, since the user should be automatically connected to the product. The easy way is to have the user paired with the device in the Bluetooth menu and then I only search the paired devices in the app for the right one. However, this is just as automatic as asking the user to switch on the location. But thanks for the help! If you have any idea, always bring it on.

Comment: Why the user should turn on GPS? The app only needs Bluetooth not GPS! I guess Google should change its policy.

Comment: This is because with bluetooth turned on it is theoretically possible to access location information and the permission for location therefore needs to be obtained, this is why the app asks for location and not GPS but GPS is often referred to as location.

Comment: Bluetooth has two sides. The first side is `advertisement`. The second side is `scanning`. Bluetooth, per se, works without any regards for `location`. But as soon as you operate on higher abstractions of `nearby.connections` API, then the `scanning` side of Bluetooth gets entangled with `location`, but the `advertisement` is not. You have to dissect which side of Bluetooth is affected and whether you are using pure Bluetooth API or the `nearby.connections` API.

Comment: But how is the Bluetooth itself working without turning the location on? I mean, if you turned the Bluetooth on from the status bar, it will automatically search and discover nearby devices without even turning the location on. How can the Bluetooth system app do this? There should be something missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Starting Android 10 the Location service must be enabled otherwise no devices will be found.

I tested `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` on Huawei P30 with Android 10 and this method alway return `false` but really the discovery is started (with Location permission granted and location service enabled). So i don't check the result of `startDiscovery()` method.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) you need to have both ***ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION*** and ***ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION*** permissions to start discovering Bluetooth devices.

```
 /**
 * From Android 10 onwards it needs Access Location to search Bluetooth Devices
 */

private void checkForLocationPermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            discoverDevices();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,}, 1);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Request Access Location while using the App, because bluetooth need location to start discovering devices
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        discoverDevices();
    } else {
        checkForLocationPermission();
    }
}
```

The above code snippet will help you to request the above permissions from the user.

*P.S*: Also, these need to specified on the Android Manifest as well.

Comment: Your answer came just in time! Thank you!